# What's the equivalent of TextClock in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock) is a widget for Android XML layouts which keeps and displays time on it's own. You just have to add the format and timezone.

Right now I don't see an equivalent in Jetpack Compose.
Should I implement it by my own with a Text composable and some time formatting libraries? Should I inflate a TextClock and make use of the backwards compatibility? Or is there a ready to use component?

Comment: "Should I implement it by my own with a Text composable and some time formatting libraries?" -- most likely. "Or is there a ready to use component?" -- I don't think that it is in the Material Design spec, so I would not expect one from Google. I am not aware of a third-party one, though there certainly could be one.

Answer (score 4):

I started with using the original TextView by adding it via the AndroidView composable. It does work but I would still appreciate an answer without "legacy" code.

```
@Composable
private fun TextClock(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    format12Hour: String? = null,
    format24Hour: String? = null, 
    timeZone: String? = null,
) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            TextClock(context).apply {
                format12Hour?.let { this.format12Hour = it }
                format24Hour?.let { this.format24Hour = it }
                timeZone?.let { this.timeZone = it }
            }
        },
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with support of TextStyle and color using legacy AndroidView.

Seems that in JetpackCompose there is no analogue for this widget, that is why this workaround should work for now, at least it could be styled using same MaterialTheme typography values.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TextClock(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    format: String = "kk:mm:ss",
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    style: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
) {
    val textColor = color.takeOrElse {
        style.color.takeOrElse {
            LocalContentColor.current
        }
    }

    val resolver = LocalFontFamilyResolver.current
    val face: Typeface = remember(resolver, style) {
        resolver.resolve(
            fontFamily = style.fontFamily,
            fontWeight = style.fontWeight ?: FontWeight.Normal,
            fontStyle = style.fontStyle ?: FontStyle.Normal,
            fontSynthesis = style.fontSynthesis ?: FontSynthesis.All
        )
    }.value as Typeface

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            android.widget.TextClock(context).apply {
                format24Hour?.let {
                    this.format24Hour = format
                }

                format12Hour?.let {
                    this.format12Hour = format
                }

                timeZone?.let { this.timeZone = it }
                textSize.let { this.textSize = style.fontSize.value }

                setTextColor(textColor.toArgb())
                typeface = face
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which made styling possible.

```
@Composable
fun ClockText() {
    val currentTimeMillis = remember {
        mutableStateOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = currentTimeMillis) {
        while (true) {
            delay(250)
            currentTimeMillis.value = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
    }

    Box() {
        Text(
            text = DateUtils.formatDateTime(LocalContext.current, currentTimeMillis.value, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp, 8.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2
        )
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/dino-su/c8edf1c206dd974b282326f3b9641ccc

Answer (score 0):

TextClock class exteds TextView class and TextView class extends View class.
However Jetpack Compose is not based on 'Views'.
So I tried to find ways to use Views in Compose and I cound find this link.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose

The link explains about AndroidView composable.
My sample code is as below and Merry Christmas!

```
@Composable
fun MyTextClock() {
    AndroidView(factory = { context ->
        TextClock(context).apply {
            format12Hour?.let {
                this.format12Hour = "a hh: mm: ss"
            }
            timeZone?.let { this.timeZone = it }
            textSize.let { this.textSize = 24f }
        }
    })
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MyTextClockPreview() {
    MyTextClock()
}
```